# Use anchor tag for calling an Action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

First I tried with

```
<input type="button" value="Something" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ActionName")'" />
```

But this is a button and I want just a link. I've seen somewhere (while wildly browsing the programming forums) a way to hide a button link behind an anchor, but couldn't find/make it.

Then I tried with

```
<a href="@Html.ActionLink("Something", "ActionName", "ControllerName")"></a>
```

(here, actually, on the page, the link looked like **Something">**, whereas the " and > shouldn't be there)

and also

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")">Something</a>
```

but the latter 2 ways (with the anchor tag) don't work, by means, I don't get directed to the other page. So, any suggestions about how to hide a button behind a link, or how to make the anchor tags run ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want an anchor, but the suggested code doesn't work. Try this way (it worked for me):

```
<a onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ActionName")'">Something</a><br />
```

It will work this way, but you will not have the hand, when you hover the link. So just add `href="#"`, like that:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ActionName")'">Something</a><br />
```

Comment: You can add the hand via css. But I don't think that was the intention. In any case, you can reference only links that address your routing config via @Url.Action. So an anchor inside the page cannot be referenced that way.

Comment: @Boranas - I didn't understand what you mean by *So an anchor inside the page cannot be referenced that way*

Answer (score 3):

Use `@Html.ActionLink("Something", "ActionName", "ControllerName")` without the `<a>` tag. It's generated automatically

Comment: It still doesn't work, though, as I am not directed to the other page. This is strange, as the name of the Action is correct. + It worked with the button.

Comment: Try using it without the controller name. You are probably getting confused with the controller names(ignore the third parameter).

Comment: @Syspect, `as I am not directed to the other page` you wont be redirected to another page. Your Controller Action method will be hit in this scenario put a breakpoint in action method the check. See break point is hit or not. and make use you use correct action name and controller name.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a asp-action="Index">Location Name</a>
```